# Code Smell for "Dependencies should be explicit" in NX Project

Tags: angular, typescript, sonarqube, nx-monorepo, nx-angular

## Project Structure

I have structured my Angular application in an NX project. Within NX the code is structured in libraries.

*Nx automatically creates TypeScript path mappings in the tsconfig.base.json file, such that they can be easily consumed by other apps or libs.*: https://nx.dev/concepts/more-concepts/applications-and-libraries

I can import from these libraries with:

```js
import { MylibModule } from '@libs/mylib/ui';
```

```
src/
|___app
|   |...
|___libs
|   |___mylib
|   |...
package.json
tsconfig.base.json
```

## The Problem

In the code analysis Sonar says *Either remove this import or add it as a dependency.*
The rule **typescript:S4328** (Dependencies should be explicit) wants me to add all imported dependencies in the `package.json`.

## Conclusion

Because the module is imported from my own library within the same repo, this is a false positive. How can I fix this?

1. I dont want to flag every smell as false positive, there are already over 300 of them
2. I dont want to disable the rule entirely, because it can be useful if a developer misses to declare a transitive dependency in the `package.json`

Any ideas? Is there some kind of configuration I could adjust to such a monorepo project?